# Changing 'names' attributes of list

Tags: r, attributes, custom-attributes, names

Hello I am analyzing some data and trying to use a package that contains a object that has to be formatted in such a way. I have never seen this type of format and I am not sure how to generate it. When I call the object in R this is the strange object:

```
> a
     A      B          C            D         E          F 
0.00000000 1.34529412 0.31571429 1.26327103 0.32615385 1.12585586
```

Here are some attributes of this object a:

```
> str(a)
 Named num [1:6] 0 1.345 0.316 1.263 0.326 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "" "A" "B" "C" ...

> class(a)
[1] "numeric"
```

I can write "a" to a .csv format with the standard write.csv command, and it formats it nicely with two columns, one column with the characters, and the other with the numbers. When I try to read it back in R using read.csv it returns it correctly as a data frame with two columns. However, the function that I am trying to use doesn't like the data frame format and prefers whatever format "a" is in.

So it is possible to take an example data set such as:

```
> L <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
> R <- c(0.00000000,1.34529412,0.31571429,1.26327103,0.32615385,1.12585586 )
> T <- list(L=L,R=R)
> Example <- as.data.frame(T)
> Example
  L     R
1 A 0.00000000
2 B 1.34529412
3 C 0.31571429
4 D 1.26327103
5 E 0.32615385
6 F 1.12585586
```

And turn it back into this?

```
     A      B          C            D         E          F 
0.00000000 1.34529412 0.31571429 1.26327103 0.32615385 1.12585586
```

With these attributes?

```
  > str(a)
     Named num [1:6] 0 1.345 0.316 1.263 0.326 ...
     - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "" "A" "B" "C" ...

    > class(a)
    [1] "numeric"
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It is a rather common construction, namely (as it were) a named numeric vector. The "names" attribute is ubiquitous in R. Suggest you read ?names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the sort of thing you're looking for:

```
newExample <- Example$R
names(newExample) <- Example$L
```

Comment: Wow.... I had not idea it was this easy! Thank you so much, and thank you Dwin for telling me where to check next.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing to disk with write.table() or write.csv(), you should learn to use save(). You can then be assured that when you load() the object back in, you will get a properly constructed copy. If you need to look at the object in an ASCII-readable format you can use dump().

Answer (score 0):

```
R <- t(Example$R)
L <- t(Example$L)
names(R) <- L
str(R)
```

num [1, 1:6] 0 1.345 0.316 1.263 0.326 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...